# UV Mapping a face that has Subdivision modifier on it?

Tags: uv, modifiers

Here is a UV Map of the face:

[image: UV Map]

You see that the letters come all the way to the edge of the hexagon.

Here is what it looks like, OK?

[image: Good]

Ah, but that’s with “Display modifier in Edit mode” turned OFF.  Here is what it really looks like, thanks to the Subdivision Surface modifier:

[image: Bad]

**How can I get the map to fill the face, when it has Subdivision?**  I’m using version 2.8 daily build, if it matters.